# stop Sql 2000 from work

Tags: sql-server

I successfully attached DB with Sql2000 to SQl2005 and I had two version 2005,2000 and I want to stop 2000 all it,s services without any effect on 2005 so what I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in "Services" in control panel and stop+disable "SQL Server Agent".

I forget exactly (been some time) which service is the DB engine but it's dependency of SQL Server Agent